# Prevent parent container from scrolling by the mouse wheel if a child (graphic) control is already scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

How to prevent the parent container from scrolling by the mouse wheel if the child (graphic) control is already focused and is scrolling?

I have a [GMap.NET WinForms control](https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET) embedded in a WinForms. Whenever that control is focused and scrolled via the mouse wheel, the parent form will also be scrolled. I just want the parent form to stay put while I'm scrolling the GMap.NET control via the mouse wheel. And when I want to scroll the parent form, I can always make GMap.NET control lose focus.
How to do what I want?

Here's my code:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.gMapControl = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl();
        this.flowLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // gMapControl
        // 
        this.gMapControl.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.gMapControl.Bearing = 0F;
        this.gMapControl.CanDragMap = true;
        this.gMapControl.EmptyTileColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy;
        this.gMapControl.GrayScaleMode = false;
        this.gMapControl.HelperLineOption = GMap.NET.WindowsForms.HelperLineOptions.DontShow;
        this.gMapControl.LevelsKeepInMemmory = 5;
        this.gMapControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(525, 1);
        this.gMapControl.MarkersEnabled = true;
        this.gMapControl.MaxZoom = 2;
        this.gMapControl.MinZoom = 2;
        this.gMapControl.MouseWheelZoomEnabled = true;
        this.gMapControl.MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionAndCenter;
        this.gMapControl.Name = "gMapControl";
        this.gMapControl.NegativeMode = false;
        this.gMapControl.PolygonsEnabled = true;
        this.gMapControl.RetryLoadTile = 0;
        this.gMapControl.RoutesEnabled = true;
        this.gMapControl.ScaleMode = GMap.NET.WindowsForms.ScaleModes.Integer;
        this.gMapControl.SelectedAreaFillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(33)))), ((int)(((byte)(65)))), ((int)(((byte)(105)))), ((int)(((byte)(225)))));
        this.gMapControl.ShowTileGridLines = false;
        this.gMapControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(198, 378);
        this.gMapControl.TabIndex = 0;
        this.gMapControl.Zoom = 0D;
        // 
        // flowLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(489, 885);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 6;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(745, 533);
        this.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.gMapControl);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl gMapControl;
    private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gMapControl.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleTerrainMap;
        gMapControl.MinZoom = 5;
        gMapControl.MaxZoom = 12;
        gMapControl.Zoom = 7.5;
        gMapControl.ShowCenter = true;
        gMapControl.DragButton = MouseButtons.Middle;
    }
}
```

This is not just a problem of the GMap.NET for sure, I've tested with other (proprietary) graphic control and it behaves all the same.

Comment: Are you saying that you're able to cause **both** the gmap control _and_ the containing window with scroll bars to respond to the mouse wheel input at the same time? _"This is not just a problem of the gmaps.net for sure"_ -- then surely you could provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem without relying on a proprietary third-party control.

Comment: @Jimi Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, I think the OP was referring to the "zoom effect" when he/she said "scrolling". In other words, "scrolling _the mouse wheel_ has an effect on both the control and its container. How can I prevent that?" is what I believe the OP's question is.

Comment: @41686d6564, yes, that's my question.. You can reproduce my problem?

Comment: @Graviton Yes, I can. So, can Jimi as he mentioned above. The question was just a little confusing because you appear to have referred to the mouse wheel as the "middle mouse" (which could be interpreted as "middle mouse button").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way around this but here's a hacky workaround to stop the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message from reaching the control and still execute the zooming logic.

Add the following class to your project:

```
public class MyGMapControl : GMapControl, IMessageFilter
{
    public MyGMapControl()
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
        if (m.HWnd == this.Handle && m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        {
            Point posOnScreen = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
            Point pos = PointToClient(posOnScreen);
            int delta = m.WParam.ToInt32();

            var args = new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.None, 0, pos.X, pos.Y, delta);
            this.OnMouseWheel(args);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, use `MyGMapControl` instead of `GMapControl`.

Here, we're creating a `MessageFilter` to intercept the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message and return `true` in `PreFilterMessage` to stop the message from reaching the control. Now, the scrolling won't occur but neither will the zooming logic because it's [implemented inside `OnMouseWheel()`](https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET/blob/master/GMap.NET/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMapControl.cs#L2439) which is triggered by the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message. So, we manually call the `OnMouseWheel()` method before returning `true` to ensure that the zooming occurs.

---

As [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) suggested in the comments, you could override `WndProc()` *of the control's parent container*, check for `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, and return if the mouse cursor is over the `GMapControl`:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
    if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
        if (gMapControl.Bounds.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition))) return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```